# How to apply filter on a dropdownbottom

Tags: flutter

I have the following code that populates a DropdownButton, but I am not able to filter content when I am editing.

I need help because I could not understand the error and how to correct the problem to make the filter.

I tried several filters without success. The filter applied below has the following error:

> Failed assertion: line 609 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty ||
>   value == null || items.where ((DropdownMenuItem  item) =>
>   item.value == value) .length == 1 ': is not true.

This error comes from the filter below:

```
if (widget.filialID != 0) {
  _select = FilialModel(key: widget.filialID);
}
```

I could not find a solution to the problem. Please help. Thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:onex_qa/data/database.dart';
import 'package:onex_qa/models/filial_model.dart';

class DropFilialDb extends StatefulWidget {
  int filialID;
  DropFilialDb({Key key, this.filialID}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DropFilialDbState createState() => _DropFilialDbState();
}

class _DropFilialDbState extends State<DropFilialDb> {
  final String _tipo = 'Filial';
  FilialModel _select;
  final _listDb = DatabaseDb().getAllFilialList();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.filialID != 0) {
      _select = FilialModel(key: widget.filialID);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 0, 2, 0),
      child: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          canvasColor: Theme.of(context).dialogBackgroundColor,
        ),
        child: FutureBuilder<List<FilialModel>>(
          future: _listDb,
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<List<FilialModel>> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
            return DropdownButton<FilialModel>(
              items: snapshot.data.map((FilialModel value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<FilialModel>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value.filial),
                );
              }).toList(),
              style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark),
              elevation: 3,
              isExpanded: true,
              hint: Text("Selecione ${_tipo}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark, fontSize: 17)),
              value: _select == null ? null : _select,
              onChanged: (FilialModel value) {
                if (value == null) {
                  _select = null;
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    _select = value;
                    widget.filialID = _select.key;
                  });
                }
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, show us `FilialModel` implementation, since the error comes from there; otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

My logical assumption is that `FilialModel` does not have equality operator defined, hence comparing two models always returns `false`. Even if they *are* the same models.

Try defining equality operator in your `FilialModel` class. That might fix the `items.where` part of the assertion that throws the error.

e.g.

```dart
class FilialModel /* extends ... */ {
  // ...,

  // Compares `key` property of current object (this) and the other object (obj)
  bool operator ==(obj) => obj is FilialModel && obj.key == this.key;

  @override
  int get hashCode => key.hashCode; // This has to be overridden too. You might want to define more complex logic here.
}
```

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: @MarceloLR Glad it worked! Please accept and/or upvote the answer if you found it helpful.